# Mysql query using index using filesort using temporary

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, filesort

I have the following two tables in my database:

*Table 1: images*

- columns: jeid [and others]
- Primary key: jeid
- Number of rows: 1.6 million

*Table 2: media_names*

- columns: jeid, media type, first_name, last_name
- primary key: jeid, media_type
- Index: first_name, last_name
- Number of rows: 1.6 million

I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT media.jeid FROM image AS media
LEFT JOIN file_girls_names AS name ON name.jeid = media.jeid AND name.media_type = "image"
ORDER BY name.first_name, name.last_name
LIMIT 0, 50
```

When I do an explain on this query, the extra column tells me:

- Using index;
- Using temporary;
- Using filesort

I'm not sure that 'using index' is bad, but I'm pretty sure that 'using temporary' and 'using filesort' are bad. The problem is, I have no idea what to do to resolve these. I've been reading all sorts of this and that, but I can't seem to find a definitive solution. Can anyone give me some assistance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to write a query, You'll have to do some testing, anyway here's my go on this.

```
SELECT `names`.`jeid`
FROM `file_girls_names` AS `names`
INNER JOIN `image` AS `media` ON `names`.`jeid` = `media`.`jeid`
WHERE `names`.`media_type` = 'image'
ORDER BY `names`.`first_name`, `names`.`last_name`
LIMIT 0, 50
```

NOTE:: This assumes you have matching columns in both tables (unless you specifically want a left join then this should be OK).